# updated groovy and spock causes propertymissing and methodmissing invocation problems

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, spock

I updated (migrating) Groovy to 3.0.4 and Spock to 2.0-M3-groovy-3.0. No other changes were made to relevant classes. The tests and code have all been in place for many years and are run regularly. What is being tested is an application the collects job run statistics. It does so dynamically as this needs to work for many different jobs, each of which may need a different set of counters.

When I run the tests with the aforementioned library upgrade, I am getting failures. For example:

```
Too many invocations for:

0 * _   (1 invocation)

Matching invocations (ordered by last occurrence):

1 * mockCounter.methodMissing('getFailureCount', [])   <-- this triggered the error
```

Nothing has changed, as I stated, other than library versions. Here is the test code (to make clear per kriegaex reply below, this is the test in it's entirety - I somehow left the when clause outside the code block):

```
when:
postProcessor.run()

then:
1 * mockContext.getOrCreateCounter('MyCategory') >> mockCounter
1 * mockContext.getOrCreateCounter('MyProductPage') >> mockPageCounter
1 * mockCounter.propertyMissing('failureCount') >> 1
1 * mockLogger.info('MyProductDeleteProcessor exited due to failures')
0 * _
```

What is interesting to me, and puzzling, is that the *methodMissing('getFailureCount', [])* is a getter for the property I am mocking.

So, I can add that method to get rid of the missing method exception - something that seems wrong - (and two more) and now my test looks like:

```
when:
postProcessor.run()

then:
1 * mockContext.getOrCreateCounter('MyCategory') >> mockCounter
1 * mockContext.getOrCreateCounter('MyProductPage') >> mockPageCounter
1 * mockCounter.propertyMissing('failureCount') >> 1
1 * mockCounter.methodMissing('getFailureCount', [])
1 * mockCounter.methodMissing('getRecoveryCount', [])
1 * mockPageCounter.methodMissing('getTotalCount', [])
1 * mockLogger.info('MyProductDeleteProcessor exited due to failures')
0 * _
```

This then leads to:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * mockCounter.propertyMissing('failureCount') >> 1
```

What the? I clearly mocked that! So I remove that line and now my test looks like:

```
when:
postProcessor.run()

then:
1 * mockContext.getOrCreateCounter('MyCategory') >> mockCounter
1 * mockContext.getOrCreateCounter('MyProductPage') >> mockPageCounter
1 * mockCounter.methodMissing('getFailureCount', [])
1 * mockCounter.methodMissing('getRecoveryCount', [])
1 * mockPageCounter.methodMissing('getTotalCount', [])
1 * mockLogger.info('MyProductDeleteProcessor exited due to failures')
0 * _
```

I then get:

```
Too many invocations for:

0 * _   (1 invocation)

Matching invocations (ordered by last occurrence):

1 * mockCounter.methodMissing('getFailureCount', [])
```

That makes no sense to me. I mocked it, as stated above. What am I missing?

The comment by kriegaex states he wants the code to the class under test. This could lead to potentially confusion and a lot of code. So I have below the partial set code from our JobStatsCounter counter, specifically the constructor and the two methods for handling missing properties and methods.

```
  public JobStatsCounter(String whatWeAreTracking, List<String> extraMetrics = ['total', 'success', 'failure', 'unmodified', 'deleted', 'recovery', 'ignored']) {
    this.whatWeAreTracking = whatWeAreTracking

    extraMetrics.each {
      this.extraMetrics.put(it, new AtomicLong())
    }
  }

  void methodMissing(String methodName, def args) {
    if (methodName.startsWith('job')) {
      String metric = StringUtils.uncapitalize(methodName - 'job')
      AtomicLong counter = extraMetrics.putIfAbsent(metric, new AtomicLong())
      if (counter == null) {
        counter = extraMetrics.putIfAbsent(metric, new AtomicLong())
      }
      counter.incrementAndGet()
      return
    }
    throw new NoSuchMethodError("Got a request for undefined method '$methodName'")
  }

  long propertyMissing(String property) {
    if (property.endsWith('Count')) {
      String metric = property - 'Count'
      if (extraMetrics.containsKey(metric)) {
        return extraMetrics[metric].get()
      }
      throw new NoSuchFieldError("Got a request for metric '$property', but there is no metric called '${metric}'")
    }
    throw new NoSuchFieldError("Got a request for undefined property '$property'")
  }
```

Comment: You are asking an interesting question, providing many details, but somehow managed to avoid showing the actual code under test and the test itself. Please fix that and notify me, then I can take another look. Besides, you also ought to explain why you (over-?) specify your test so strictly. This looks like bad testing style to me. Testing interactions is meant to be used for cases in which it is vital to the feature you want to verify. What makes you want to test that Groovy meta programming works as designed? And why is the absence of internal method calls (`0 * ...`) relevant?

Comment: @kriegaex I did a lot of editing and hopefully provided all that is needed. Regarding you  comments on strict mocking, I tend to agree. I am a consultant and have only been with the client for a few months. This practice seems the norm here. There is an over reliance on mocking here too, imo, but it is what it is. This test in particular is meant to assure that other things do not happen, such as making rest calls when there is a failure when processing the job (hence the failureCount property is mocked to return 1). I hope I have provided enough info. If more is needed, I will try to provide.

Comment: Sorry Bill, but this is not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) despite the update. What does it cost you to post full classes with imports, class and method names, packages etc.? Why be stingy with details? You have a tricky question with a problem only occurring under a specific Spock version, so it is your job to make it reproducible for the community you require help from. Your test is still so sketchy, I cannot even see what kinds of objects `postProcessor`, `mockContext` etc. are and how they are initialised. Please distil a small MCVE from your big code base.